# ruby on rails: application layout appearing in popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR application, I have a link which opens up a popup window. I am using a different stylesheet for the popup but the problem is that it's displaying the menubar & banner defined in the main application.html.erb.
I want my popup window to be simple and don't want it to contain the main banner of the menu bar and although am using a seperate stylesheet, the main menu/banner are still displayed.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 4):

Here's some [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

If you don't want the layout to render

```
render :layout => false
```

or

```
layout nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
render :layout => false
```

in the action that is used in the popup

Comment: Thnak you so much :) This is exactly what i wanted